# Why Does Part Work Much Slower on Modified List?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

Consider the following list:

```
tabb = RandomReal[{0.0000001, 10^5}, {10^6, 80}];
```

I want to extract, e.g., the columns from 1 to 20. It is reasonably fast:

```
tabb[[All, Range[1, 20]]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.077998

However, if I first make the following replacement,

```
tabb[[All, {2}]] = tabb[[All, {22}]] = Table[{i}, {i, 1, Length[tabb], 1}];
```

it starts working much slower:

```
tabb[[All, Range[1, 20]]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.426746

Twe two questions I have are:

1. Is it possible to speed up extraction of the columns compared to the first example?
2. What is the reason for slowdown in the second example?

Comment: There is also `On[["Packing"]]` (see [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/On.html?q=On)) which will produce a message of the type ``Developer`FromPackedArray::punpack: Unpacking array with dimensions {1000000,1} in call to System`Private`PackedList.`` if a packed array is unpacked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> what is the reason for slowdown for the second example?

It got unpacked, that is why

```
tabb=RandomReal[{0.0000001,10^5},{10^6,80}];
Developer`PackedArrayQ[tabb]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
tabb[[All, {2}]] = tabb[[All, {22}]] = Table[{i}, {i, 1, Length[tabb], 1}];
Developer`PackedArrayQ[tabb]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Packed array are much faster.

Answer (score 7):

The reason of the slowdown is the mixture of reals with integers.

```
tabb = RandomReal[{0.0000001, 10^5}, {10^6, 80}];

tabb[[All, Range[1, 20]]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

0.06858

Notice the `1.` instead of `1`:

```
tabb[[All, {2}]] = 
  tabb[[All, {22}]] = Table[{i}, {i, 1., Length[tabb], 1}];

tabb[[All, Range[1, 20]]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

0.066825

Thanks to Nasser:

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ[tabb]
```

True

Comment: Can you clarify whether or not the lists remain packed using this example?

Comment: Using the same test as Nasser, one can see that `tabb` remains packed - see updated answer.