# How to "complete" the table by making all of its rows to have the same number of elements?

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax, table

Consider the following table:

```
len = 10^6;
nmax=RandomInteger[{5,6}];
nvals = RandomInteger[{1, nmax}, len];
table = Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 2*nvals[[i]]], {i, 1, len, 1}];
```

Each row is made of 2n elements, where `n` may vary from 1 to some number `nmax`. We do not know this `nmax` a priori and may only extract it by finding the row of `table` with the maximal number of elements.

Could you please tell me how to complement the rows `table` with some test elements, say -999, such that each row would have `2nmax` elements? I.e., for `nmax = 4` and the given row being `{1,2,3,4}`, it must be converted into `{1,2,3,4,-999,-999,-999,-999}`.

Also, how to make it [packed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/291978/why-does-part-work-much-slower-on-modified-list) afterward (as it seems that the complementing procedure will make it unpacked)?

Comment: `PadRight[table, {Automatic, 2 nmax}, -999]`?

Comment: @kglr : Thanks! However, nmax is unknown a priori, we may extract it only from `table`.

Comment: @kglr : also, ```Developer`PackedArrayQ[table1]``` returns `False`, where `table1` is the table obtained with the help of your command. It means that any work with it will be much slower than with the packed one.

Comment: `PadRight[table, Automatic, -999]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter that `nmax` is unknown a priori, because `PadRight` will automatically append `-999` up to the length of the longest matrix row. We can see this clearly in the answer of `kglr`. And equal row lengths are required to pack the array (you cannot pack "ragged" matrices).

```
len = 10^6;
nmax = RandomInteger[{5, 6}];
nvals = RandomInteger[{1, nmax}, len];
table = Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 2*nvals[[i]]], {i, 1, len, 1}];

res = PadRight[table, Automatic, -999]

Developer`PackedArrayQ[res]
```

False

```
pack = Developer`ToPackedArray @ N @ res;

Developer`PackedArrayQ[pack]
```

True

If you pad with a real value, `-999.0` for example, you don't need the `N`.

Answer (score 3):

```
SeedRandom[1];
len = 10;
nmax = RandomInteger[{5, 6}];
nvals = RandomInteger[{1, nmax}, len];
table = Table[Array[Subscript[\[Alpha], #] &, 2*nvals[[i]]], {i, 1, len, 1}];

Grid[table]
```

[image]

```
PadRight[table, Automatic, β] // Grid
```

[image]